# Matrix multiplication: What is $\mathbf A^3$ and $\mathbf A^n$?

Tags: matrices, exponentiation

Suppose there is matrix **A**.

I know that **A<sup>2</sup>** = **A $\cdot $A**

But what if it is **A<sup>3</sup>**?

Is it **A $\cdot $A $\cdot$A** OR **A<sup>2</sup> $\cdot$ A** OR **A  $\cdot$ A<sup>2</sup>**?

So basically my question is what is **A<sup>n</sup>**?

Comment: Hint: $A(BC)=(AB)C$ usually on matrices, i.e. associativity holds.

Comment: Try it out with some random $2\times 2$ matrix, or if you're feeling up for it, a $3\times 3$ matrix (that's $108$ multiplications and $72$ additions to show that $A^2 A = AA^2$, though, lots of room to make a mistake). You should see that it doesn't matter which order you do it in.

Comment: @Arthur Oh I got it. I think example is best way.

Comment: Some related older posts: [Do matrices have a “to the power of” operator?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/465829/do-matrices-have-a-to-the-power-of-operator) and [Matrix P to the power of 4, i.e $P^4$, is this the same as $P^2 \cdot P^2$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/258712/matrix-p-to-the-power-of-4-i-e-p4-is-this-the-same-as-p2-cdot-p2)

Answer (score 2):

$A^3 = A(AA)=AA^2=(AA)A=A^2A$. This comes from the associativity of matrices. In the case of $A^n =A \cdot A\cdot ...\cdot A$, $n$-times

Answer (score 1):

Matrix multiplication is associative, so it is all those things.

Comment: nope. AB != BA. Consider $A^2$ as B. So we will get 3 different matrices. AAA, AB and BA

Comment: @Freddy It is true that matrices do not in general commute, but $A$ and $A^2$ _do_ commute.

Comment: @Freddy $AB\neq BA$ has nothing to do with the fact that $A\cdot(A\cdot A) = (A\cdot A)\cdot A$

Comment: @5xum It might, if you look at it as a commutation rather than an association. However, Freddy, it is not the case that $AB \neq BA$. It's rather that "$AB = BA$ does not always hold"

Answer (score 1):

You doubt is very common with people without a course in abstract algebra.

It doesn't matter if you calculate $(A\cdot A)\cdot A$ or $A\cdot (A\cdot A)$. This is true because the associativity holds for matrices multiplication. Note that you can write the multiplication without parentheses just if you have $(A\cdot A)\cdot A=A\cdot (A\cdot A)$.

Let's take some examples:

Products in the real numbers are associative, for example $(20\cdot 4)\cdot 2 =20\cdot (4\cdot 2)$, because $(20\cdot 4)\cdot 2=160$ and $20\cdot (4\cdot 2)=160$. Then the multiplication is well-defined in this example and you can write $20\cdot 4\cdot 2=160$.

Division are not associative, for example $(20\div 4)\div 2\neq 20\div(4\div2)$, because $(20\div 4)\div 2=2,5$ and $20\div(4\div2)=10$. So   $20\div 4\div 2$ is not well-defined because it would have two results $10$ and $2,5$.

Any questions I would be glad to help.